# Elasticsearch complex aggregation One nested value minus second nested value and group by third nested value

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I'm really confused.

I created a nested structure with three types of data inside, **addfields** is nested data type with properties:

- **id** type **integer**
- **value** type **text** fielddata **true**
- **value_numeric** type **double**

Data inside elastic looks like:

```
{
  "_index": "item",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_source": {
    "id": 1,
    "addfields": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "value_numeric": 10
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "value_numeric": 10
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "value": "Daniel"
      },
    ]
  },
}
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
  "_index": "item",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_source": {
    "id": 2,
    "addfields": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "value_numeric": 150
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "value_numeric": 100
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "value": "Daniel"
      },
    ]
  },
}
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
  "_index": "item",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_source": {
    "id": 2,
    "addfields": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "value_numeric": 250
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "value_numeric": 200
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "value": "Richard"
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

I want to aggregate this data like:

**addfields[1]** **-** **addfields[2]** and group them by **addfields[3]**

I tried to use the **bucket_script** as following, but things didn't go well.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    'nested' => [
        'path' => 'addfields',
    ],
    "addfields": {
      "aggs": {
        "leftfield": {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
                "must": {
                    {
                        "match": {"addfields.id": 1}
                    }
                }
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "values": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "value_numeric",
                    "size": 9999
                }
            }
          }
        },
        "rightfield": {
            "filter": {
            "bool": {
                "must": {
                    {
                        "match": {"addfields.id": 2}
                    }
                }
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "values": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "value_numeric",
                    "size": 9999
                }

        },
        "calculate": {
          "bucket_script": {
            "buckets_path": { 
              "left": "leftfield",
              "right": "rightfield"
            },
            "script": {
              "source": "params.leftfield - params.rightfield"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In your example structure, doc 1 and 2 have the name "Daniel" in the field "value". Can you please tell if this intended to be represented as "the same Daniel"? The "value" field is intended to be unique?

Comment: yes, this is the same "Daniel". "value" dont need to be unique